# Adding Input Value Into An Object (Vue.js)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to create a table that contains a bunch of input text fields. My goal is to get the value of an input, and add it into an object with the row ID as the key. I tried to use `v-model`, but I lost. I actually managed to get all necessary pieces, but I couldn't put them together. So, I hope someone can help me on that.

Here is my input box:

```
<input
  type="text"
  :id="['tv_code_' + listItem.asset_id]"
  @input="getInputValue('tv_code', listItem.asset_id)"
>
```

The function:

```
getInputValue(obj, key) {
  var inputValue = document.getElementById(obj + "_" + key).value;
  if (inputValue.length > 0) { 
    this.$set(this.form.obj, key, inputValue);
  } else {
    this.$delete(this.form.obj, key);
  }
}
```

And vue.js data structure:

```
data(){
  form: new Form({
    tv_code: {}
  })
}
```

When I type something in the input, I'm getting these 3 errors:

```
[Vue warn]: Cannot set reactive property on undefined, null, or primitive value: undefined
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '1' in undefined"
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '1' in undefined
```

I don't understand what is `undefined` because when I try console log `obj`, `key`, and `inputValue`, I'm getting the correct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is related to [`Vue.set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set)/`this.$set`, so the problem is likely on this line:

```
 this.$set(this.form.obj, key, inputValue)
```

It indicates that the first/target argument (i.e., `this.form.obj`) is either `undefined`, `null`, or a primitive (i.e., `string`, `number`, `Symbol`, `boolean`). Since `this.form` is declared as `new Form()`, the problem is likely inside the `Form` class (whose source is not posted in the question). Let's look at the three possibilities...

#### `form.obj` is `undefined`

- `Form` does not declare `obj`

  ```
   class Form {
     constructor() {
       /* no obj anywhere */  // DON'T DO THIS
     }
   }
  ```
- `Form` sets `obj` to `undefined`

  ```
   class Form {
     constructor() {
       this.obj = undefined;  // DON'T DO THIS
     }
   }
  ```

#### `form.obj` is `null`

- `Form` sets `obj` to `null`

  ```
   class Form {
     constructor() {
       this.obj = null;      // DON'T DO THIS
     }
   }
  ```

#### `form.obj` is a primitive

- `Form` sets `obj` to a value that is either `string`, `number`, `symbol`, or `boolean`

  ```
   class Form {
     constructor() {
       this.obj = 'foo';     // DON'T DO THIS
       this.obj = 1;         // DON'T DO THIS
       this.obj = Symbol();  // DON'T DO THIS
       this.obj = true;      // DON'T DO THIS
     }
   }
  ```

## Solution

The fix would be to declare `obj` as an object:

```
class Form {
  constructor() {
    this.obj = { /*...*/ };
  }
}
```

```js
class Form {
  constructor({ tv_code }) {
    this.tv_code = tv_code;
    this.obj = { foo: null };
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      listItem: {
        asset_id: 'foo'
      },
      form: new Form({
        tv_code: {}
      }),
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getInputValue(obj, key) {
      const inputValue = document.getElementById(obj + "_" + key).value;
      if (inputValue.length > 0) {
        this.$set(this.form.obj, key, inputValue);
      } else {
        this.$delete(this.form.obj, key);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.7"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input
  type="text"
  :id="['tv_code_' + listItem.asset_id]"
  @input="getInputValue('tv_code', listItem.asset_id)"
>
  <pre>{{form.obj}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tony. You are right about the source of the issue. Actually, I don't have any object called 'obj'. I was trying to pass an argument. But it looks for form.obj instead of form.tv_code. I think I need to make some researches about passing argument on Vue.js. document.getElementById(obj + "_" + key).value works perfectly fine with argument and it gives me the correct IDs which are tv_code_1, tv_code_2, .... tv_code_n. Thanks again.